# jquery iframe event working with mozilla?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wysihtml5

I use html5 wysiwyg editor. Editor loads dinamically iframe and I want to monitor `keydown` event on this editor.

Loaded iframe looks like that:

```
<iframe class="wysihtml5-sandbox" security="restricted" allowtransparency="true">
<html>
  <head><meta charset="UTF-8"></head>
   <body marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" id="descriptionkb" contenteditable="true" 
    class="form-     control editor wysihtml5-editor" spellcheck="true" 
   style="color: rgb(85, 85, 85); cursor: auto; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal;
      line-height: 20px; letter-spacing: normal; text-align: start; text-decoration: none; 
    text-indent: 0px; text-rendering: auto; word-break: normal; word-wrap: break-word; 
     word-spacing: 0px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
           <span id="_wysihtml5-undo" class="_wysihtml5-temp"></span>
    </body>
</html>
</iframe>
```

What i do to monitor `keydown` event is :

```
$('iframe.wysihtml5-sandbox').contents().on('keydown', '#descriptionkb', function(e){ 
        // execute code  on keydown event
  });
```

This works great with chrome and IE but not working with mozilla. I've tried different ways to acces event but none of them worked in mozilla. Where I am wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from https://github.com/xing/wysihtml5/wiki/Events

> Make sure that the wysihtml iframe is fully loaded before registering
>   events like this, otherwise results may vary across browsers. One way
>   to ensure that the iframe is fully loaded is to define functions like
>   the above as a callback on the editor’s “load” function.

Comment: Oh I totaly forgot about load because it was working on other browsers without load... After load it works with mozilla. For first time I love IE.